# A-Frame only show vive controls if they exist

Tags: javascript, aframe

Is there a way to only show Vive controllers from A-Frame if they are actually connected. But if not do not show the controllers?

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/vive-controls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a component to hide the controllers if they aren't found:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('hide-if-no-controllers', {
  init: function () {
    if (this.sceneEl.systems['tracked-controls'].controllers.length) { return; }  // Alternatively, use navigator.getGamepads().
    this.setAttribute('visible', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, but isn't it logical to have this as part of the default VIVE controller component? Should I try to add this to the VIVE component? And thank you!

Comment: Not quite sure. It'd would be helpful, but then it sets precedent for A-Frame trying to handle cross-platform responsiveness. Worried about it making A-Frame less simple and putting more load on A-Frame.